# Proving that a single sheet hyperboloid is doubly ruled

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm quite stuck on this problem; we're being asked to prove that the surface $x^2+y^2-z^2=1$ is doubly ruled, by showing that it can be parametrized as $a(u,v) = \alpha (u)+v\beta(u)$.

The base curve that I have is the unit circle in the plane, so I've set $\alpha(u) = (\cos u, \sin u,0)$.

We're given a hint to rewrite the equation of the surface as $(y-z)(y+z) = (1-x)(1+x)$, and then use this to determine the lines of the ruling as the intersection of two planes, which I've started to do; I've written out the 4 planes that this tells us
$$x+y-z=1$$
$$x+y+z=1$$
$$-x+y-z=1$$
$$-x+y+z=1$$
and I've calculated that the line of intersection for the first two would have direction $(1,1,0)$, and the line of intersection of the last two would have direction $(1,-1,0)$.

However, once I get there I'm not sure what to do anymore...

Comment: Where did you get these four equations?

Comment: They're from the the equations of the the plane, I realized later on that I may be about it the wrong way, right now, I've set it up such that my lines are described by the intersections of $$ y-z=a(1-x), y+z=(1/a)(1+x)$$ and $$y-z=b(1+x), y+z=(1/b)(1-x)$$, where a and b are some parameters that I want to get in terms of my parametrization angle $u$, but now I'm stuck again, I think I'm going about it the right way?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure where your professor is headed, although this will work at $(\pm1,0)$. When I assign this exercise, I just expect students to plug in the parametric equations of a line through a point on that baee circle and solve for the line to be contained in the hyperboloid.

Comment: It's definitely more than possible that I'm just confused, I'll go about it that way, that you very much!